# Are there differences between the parameters of different versions of ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

I want to obtain a different raw video for each frame of an MP4 file.
 My instruction works in an old version of ffmpeg but not in the new one.

In the mp4 file there are 137 frames. It is checked. The versions are installed on different machines.

Versions 2.8.15:

```
$ ffmpeg -i ./video.mp4 -vf fps=30 -vframes 137 -vcodec rawvideo -s '1920x1080' -pix_fmt gray -threads 0 frame%08d.raw
ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from './video.mp4':
   Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42
    creation_time   : 2019-03-11 16:16:54
  Duration: 00:00:04.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14014 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 13816 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-03-11 16:16:54
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-03-11 16:16:54
Output #0, image2, to 'frame%08d.raw':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: rawvideo (Y800 / 0x30303859), gray, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-03-11 16:16:54
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 rawvideo
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  137 fps= 73 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:04.56 bitrate=N/A dup=1 drop=0    
video:277425kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Version 4.1.4:

```
$ ffmpeg -i ./video.mp4 -vf fps=30 -vframes 137 -vcodec rawvideo -s '1920x1080' -pix_fmt gray -threads 0 frame%08d.raw
ffmpeg version 4.1.4-1~deb10u1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8 (Debian 8.3.0-6)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version='1~deb10u1' --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x558d1a5bb880] st: 0 edit list: 1 Missing key frame while searching for timestamp: 0
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x558d1a5bb880] st: 0 edit list 1 Cannot find an index entry before timestamp: 0.
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from './video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42
    creation_time   : 2019-03-11T16:16:54.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:04.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 14014 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 13816 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-03-11T16:16:54.000000Z
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-03-11T16:16:54.000000Z
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, image2, to 'frame%08d.raw':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: rawvideo (Y800 / 0x30303859), gray,     1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 497664 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-03-11T16:16:54.000000Z
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 rawvideo
frame=  136 fps= 25 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:04.53 bitrate=N/A speed=0.834x    
video:275400kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

In the latest version, I expect 137 files but the amount is 136.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old version did not have support for edit lists. Technically, some frames are not meant for presentation but only as reference, but since you want all frames, use

```
ffmpeg -ignore_editlist 1 -i ./video.mp4 -vsync 0 -c:v rawvideo -s '1920x1080' -pix_fmt gray frame%08d.raw
```